# Why are there 3 Arguments in Choice? There are 2 Arguments

Tags: python

There is not much to say, I imported choice in random and I get an error, that there are given 3 arguments and there are just 2 possible, but there are just 2 numbers. Its written in Python
`TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

```
import pyautogui
import time
from random import choice


time.sleep(7)

for i in range(5):
    f = open('D:\Ehre', 'r')
    for word in f:
            pyautogui.typewrite(word)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            time.sleep(choice(181, 301))
```

Thanks

Comment: As far as I can tell, choice is expecting a list or string. What behavior are you aming for, do you want either 181 or 301, or anything in between?

Comment: Please paste in the actual error, not your paraphrasing of it.

Comment: If you want choose randomly either 181 and 301, you can use `choice([181, 301])`.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You didn't include the error message (initially) and just doing a quick search for it would have revealed your problem. The unclear question and low effort is probably what the downvotes are indicating.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to choose either 181 or 301, use

```
random.choice([181, 301])
```

(note the additional list-constructing brackets).

If you want a number between 181 and 301, use

```
random.randint(181, 301)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write:

```
choice([181, 301])
```